# Open bootstrap tabs with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I want to open bootstrap tabs and instantly show the href page inside each tab onclick. I have this small code below but it does not output any page.

**html**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="prodTabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab_basic" data-url="http://localhost/bioinformatica/stuff/pagina.html">Basic</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_images" data-url="httpt://localhost/bioinformatica/stuff/pagina.html">pagina</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_videos" data-url="www.facebook.com">FB</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab_basic" class="tab-pane active"></div>
        <div id="tab_images" class="tab-pane active"></div>
        <div id="tab_videos" class="tab-pane active"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#tabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
    var href = this.hash;  
    var pane = $(this);

    // ajax load from data-url

    $(href).load(url,function(result){      
        pane.tab('show');
    });
});

// load first tab content
$('#tab_basic').load($('.active a').attr("data-url"),function(result){
  $('.active a').tab('show');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepend `http://` in the `data-url` or else the code will append the domain where it is already running.

Also, even after prepending `http://` it is not gonna work because of `Cross Domain Request`. Dont worry your code is fine, it is just that `http://google.com` doesn't allow any other to make an `AJAX` request to it.

Just try it with some file already present on your local `server`.

Comment: I added http:// and it is still blank , when i click the second tab for example the url  i  get is : http://localhost/bioinformatica/Main_page/#tab_images

Comment: I dont think so, Just check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/82jzxw5x/ and open the console [F12]. Now click on any link and see the error in the console. It is clearly specifying which link `.load()` is trying to load.

Comment: The error on clicking `Basic` is `GET http://localhost/bioinformatica/stuff/pagina.html net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` which clearly says it was trying to call `http://localhost/bioinformatica/stuff/pagina.html `

Comment: i uploaded a print of clicking second tab. You think XAMPP may be the cause ?

Comment: I run the jsfiddle code, click Basic and i get an allert: withhttp://localhost/bioinformatica/stuff/pagina.html#tab_basic  [Object object]

Comment: Look you are loading the Page using AJAX, Its not gonna change the URL in the address bar. Its just gonna fetch the content of `http://localhost/bioinformatica/stuff/pagina.html` and it is gonna put the content inside the `div` with `id` `#tab_basic`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70960/discussion-between-void-and-joao-pedro).